# Gradle can't use ant optional (for example ScriptRunner in script task)

Tags: gradle

When I execute an imported ant task, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.ScriptRunner
```

I know I use scripts in many places inside my tasks. I use them like this:

```
<script manager="bsf" language="beanshell" classpath="${bshJar}"><![CDATA[
```

I guess I somehow must add a dependency to ant-apache-bsf jar. I tried

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.apache.ant:ant-apache-bsf:+'
  }  
}

// Confirm the classpath contains optional jar.
// The jar contains the required class.
buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it }

def sc = new org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.ScriptRunner();
println "sure we are able to create a script runner object: $sc"

ant.importBuild "build.xml"
```

No success. There is an article in Gradle User Guide with a promising title [42.9 Ant optional dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#buildLogic). Unfortunately the only thing I understand from this article is that my solution won't work. The example given there doesn't help.

What do I do to make use of my ant scripting tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the answer to accept, just a **workaround**.

Currently you use *Beanshell* scripts, through BSF engine. You may **convert your scripts to *Javascript***, which do not require any dependencies since JDK 6. The syntax is a bit different, but the following ant tasks work in gradle+ant out of the box:

```
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
```